# Why resuming from hibernation is so slow?

Tags: windows-10, hibernate

On a Windows 10 laptop, I noticed that resuming from hibernation takes quite a while.

```
RAM:                32 GB
hiberfil.sys size:  13 GB 
SSD read speed:    2-3 GB/s
SSD type:           WD SN730 1TB NVMe

Resume form hibernate: 30 seconds
Regular boot:          11 seconds (Fast Startup enabled)
Regular boot:          16 seconds (Fast Startup disabled)
```

(all timings from "after BIOS startup is finished and disk loading starts" to
"Windows login screen appears")

By those data, assuming that all of the hibernation file is used, it should take 5-7 seconds to load it. But in reality is takes 30 seconds of disk activity, until the screen shows something (the login/lock screen, before that it just shows the spinning dots).

So it is 5 times slower that calculated above. Why is that? What are typical values?

It is a Lenovo P53 latop with Intel i7-9850H CPU, Windows is up to date, version 21H2

Comment: how long does a boot not from hinernation take

Comment: what is your make and model of SSD?

Comment: Is hibernation really working?  Is the computer shutting down instead

Comment: @Keltari The SSD is a WD SN730 1TB NVMe. It really does 3GB/s, benchmarked.

Comment: @John Hibernation works fine (except the resume speed). All the programs and data are there after resuming.

Comment: how long does a boot that is NOT from hinernation take?

Comment: @JaromandaX added to the question

Comment: If you run admin elevated cmd `powercfg /hiberate off`, reboot, and then run `powercfg /hibernate on`, reboot, sign on, then hibernate, does it take just as long or does that speed it up coming out of hibernation? Maybe the hiberfil.sys was corrupt on disk. See this note from MS regarding bitlocker disk encryption: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-of-hibernation-may-cause-slower-starts-and-resumes-when-bitlocker-drive-encryption-is-enabled-1006aec5-1f82-9cb0-f479-bcf5ec1f47ed. Lastly, upgrade BIOS firmware if not up-to-date and consider upgrading to Win 10 22H2 feature update.